# Writing into Each LBA on Disk

Tags: scsi

There is a need to write into each LBA on the disk using SCSI CDB. Here i have constructed a while/for loop for writing into each LBA. I am using 10 byte CDB .

How do i represent 32 bit LBA so that it iterates from LBA 0 to Maximun LBA .  What should be the data  Tranfer lenght if i am planning to write on each LBA . Each LBA size 512 bytes.

```
for(i=0;i<=max_lba;i++)
{
    ccb->cam_flags = DATA_OUT;
    ccb->cdb[0] = 0x2A;     /*  0x2A SCSI Opcode for write 10  CDB */
    ccb->cdb[1] = 0;
    ccb->cdb[2] = ?? ( LBA )
    ccb->cdb[3] = ?? ( LBA )
    ccb->cdb[4] = ?? ( LBA )       
    ccb->cdb[5] = ?? ( LBA )
    ccb->cdb[6] = 0;
    ccb->cdb[7] = ??      /* Data Transfer Length */
    ccb->cdb[8] = ??      /* Data Transfer Length */ 
    ccb->cdb[9] = 0;

    ccb->ccb_address = (long)ccb;
    ptr_data = (byte *)(buffer  + ccb->data_buf_ptr);

    data_pattern = i + (i << 4);
    buffer[ccb->data_buf_ptr ] = data_pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the lba similar to this (but note that it will be really slow if you  are going to write all of a large drive ... so it would be better if you write a large number of blocks, perhaps 1MB then adjust the next LBA accordingly).

```
cdb[2] = (i & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
cdb[3] = (i &   0xFF0000) >> 16;
cdb[4] = (i &     0xFF00) >> 8;
cdb[5] = (i &       0xFF);
```

For the above, set the number of blocks to 1:
    cdb[7] = 0;
    cdb[8] = 1;

Again, you will be waiting all day for a large drive so make the changes to write a large number of blocks in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hmm, looking again I don't see where you did the write in each iteration. Don't forget to do that.

Comment: ccb->cam_flags = DATA_OUT;

    ccb->cdb[0] = 0x2A;    
    ccb->cdb[1] = 0;
    ccb->cdb[2] = (i & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
 ccb->cdb[3] = (i &   0xFF0000) >> 16;
 ccb->cdb[4] = (i &     0xFF00) >> 8;
 ccb->cdb[5] = (i &       0xFF);
    ccb->cdb[6] = 0;
    ccb->cdb[7] = 0;      /* Data Transfer Length */
    ccb->cdb[8] = 1;      /* Data Transfer Length of 1 block  */ 
    ccb->cdb[9] = 0;

    ccb->ccb_address = (long)ccb;
    ptr_data = (byte *)(buffer  + ccb->data_buf_ptr);

    data_pattern = i + (i << 4);
    buffer[ccb->data_buf_ptr ] = data_pattern;

Comment: Many thanks for the help . Can I contact you directly for SCSI CDB related queries ? I will really appreciate if you can share your Email id.